# Programmatically affecting load order of perspectives

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, perspectives

So, I'm working on an Eclipse Plugin which includes a custom view based on analysis of source code. The majority of the time, it works great. However, if I quit Eclipse with that view open, when I reopen it, it runs into an error with either `IWorkbenchWindow.getActivePage()` or `IWorkbenchPage.getEditorReferences()` returning null. This inconsistency seems to be because <strike>the view has the focus when Eclipse quits and is the first thing that Eclipse tries to reconstruct on start up.</strike> the focus is on a non-window shell (I don't fully understand this, but that's what [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_find_the_active_workbench_page?) said). Is there a workaround so that I can ensure that Eclipse fully loads its `IWorkbenchWindow` before my custom plugin regardless of what has the focus when Eclipse closes?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use the above lines in your constructor or in `createPartControls()`

Comment: It gets called indirectly through createPartControls()

Comment: That is strange as the workbench has been completely set-up by then - but the active page might be set yet. You can consider using the site instead: `getSite().getPage()...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider using the site instead: `getSite().getPage()`...

Answer (score 1):

Tonny Madsen pointed out in the comments that, from within a View, I can access the Active Page from `getSite().getPage()`, which solved the issues.